# what is sprintf in c#?

Tags: c#, c++

what does this c++ code look like in c#?

```
 sprintf(ff, "\\\\.\\%s", device);
```

Comment: i would like to convert the above to c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string ff = string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}", device);
```

or, better yet:

```
var ff = string.Format(@"\\.\{0}", device);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `@`, then you don't need to type so many `\` (escape sequences):

```
string ff = string.Format(@"\\.\{0}", device);
```

Looks clean!

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
ff = "\\\\.\\" + device;
```

Alternatively, you can use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
ff = string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}", device);
```